# SwiftUI how to animate each character in textfield?

Tags: swift, swiftui

As a user types characters in a textfield, I would like to display some animation on each newly typed character (kinda like how Cash App animates numbers but I'd like to implement it for alphabetical characters as well).

[image]

Is it possible to do this in SwiftUI? My intuition is that I might have to bridge to UIKit for more nuanced access to a `textfield`'s element but not sure how to actually implement that.

Comment: Do you want to invoke an animation on the textfield itself or another part of the view? I don't think you have to use UIKit for any of these cases, is possible with SwiftUI.

Comment: On textfield itself as users type in characters onto the field. If this is the case, how can it be animated using SwiftUI alone? I thought the animation scope only wraps the `textfield` but not necessarily every each character in it?

Comment: which kind animation? do have an example of what you want?

Comment: for example, upon typing, the newly typed character slides from left.

Comment: You cannot do it with standard API from Apple, need a custom code for that. Also you mentioned about UIKit, i do not think that would possible with that either.

Comment: Maybe with Core Text, but it’s going to be complicated

Comment: Why not create a textfield with opacity 0 and creating an observer of the binding variable which animates the string in a normal Textblock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create a "Fake" `TextField` that appears over the real one. Then show the characters in a `ForEach`.

It is done with `FocusState` in iOS 15

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct AnimatedInputView: View {
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Int?
    @State var text: String = ""
    //If all the fonts match the cursor is better aligned 
    @State var font: Font = .system(size: 48, weight: .bold, design: .default)
    @State var color: Color = .gray
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
            //To maintain size in between the 2 views
            Text(text)
                .font(font)
                .opacity(0)
                .overlay(
                    //This textField will be invisible
                    TextField("", text: $text)
                        .font(font)
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                        .focused($isFocused, equals: 1)
                )
                .background(
                    ZStack{
                        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0, content: {
                            //You need an array of unique/identifiable characters
                            let uniqueArray = text.uniqueCharacters()
                            ForEach(uniqueArray, id: \.id, content: { char in
                                CharView(char: char.char, isLast: char == uniqueArray.last, font: font)
                                
                            })
                        })
                    }.opacity(1)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                    
                )
            
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    //Bring focus to the hidden TextField
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
                        isFocused = 1
                    })
                })
        }
        .padding()
        .border(color)
        .font(.title)
        //Bring focus to the hidden textfield
        .onTapGesture {
            isFocused = 1
        }
    }
}
struct CharView: View{
    var char: Character
    var isLast: Bool
    var font: Font
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 0.75
    var body: some View{
        Text(char.description)
            .font(font)
            .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
            .scaleEffect(scale)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                //Animate only if last character
                if isLast{
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.5)){
                        scale = 1
                    }
                }else{
                    scale = 1
                }
            })
    }
}
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct AnimatedInputView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnimatedInputView()
    }
}
//Convert String to Unique characers
extension String{
    func uniqueCharacters() -> [UniqueCharacter]{
        let array: [Character] = Array(self)
        return array.uniqueCharacters()
    }
    func numberOnly() -> String {
        self.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "-0123456789.").inverted)
    }
    
}
extension Array where Element == Character {
    
    func uniqueCharacters() -> [UniqueCharacter]{
        var array: [UniqueCharacter] = []
        
        for char in self{
            array.append(UniqueCharacter(char: char))
        }
        return array
    }
    
}

//String/Characters can be repeating so yu have to make them a unique value
struct UniqueCharacter: Identifiable, Equatable{
    var char: Character
    var id: UUID = UUID()
}
```

Here is a sample version that. only takes numbers like the calculator sample

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct AnimatedInputView: View {
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Int?
    @State var text: String = ""
    //If all the fonts match the cursor is better aligned 
    @State var font: Font = .system(size: 48, weight: .bold, design: .default)
    @State var color: Color = .gray
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
            Text("$").font(font)
            //To maintain size in between the 2 views
            Text(text)
                .font(font)
                .opacity(0)
                .overlay(
                    //This textField will be invisible
                    TextField("", text: $text)
                        .font(font)
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                        .focused($isFocused, equals: 1)
                        .onChange(of: text, perform: { value in
                               if Double(text) == nil{
                                   //Leaves the negative and decimal period
                                   text = text.numberOnly()
                               }
                               //This condition can be improved.
                               //Checks for 2 occurences of the decimal period
                               //Possible solution
                               while text.components(separatedBy: ".").count > 2{
                                   color = .red
                                   text.removeLast()
                               }

                               //This condition can be improved.
                               //Checks for 2 occurences of the negative
                               //Possible solution
                               while text.components(separatedBy: "-").count > 2{
                                   color = .red
                                   text.removeLast()
                               }
                               color = .gray

                           })
                )
                .background(
                    ZStack{
                        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0, content: {
                            //You need an array of unique/identifiable characters
                            let uniqueArray = text.uniqueCharacters()
                            ForEach(uniqueArray, id: \.id, content: { char in
                                CharView(char: char.char, isLast: char == uniqueArray.last, font: font)
                                
                            })
                        })
                    }.opacity(1)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                    
                )
            
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    //Bring focus to the hidden TextField
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
                        isFocused = 1
                    })
                })
        }
        .padding()
        .border(color)
        .font(.title)
        //Bring focus to the hidden textfield
        .onTapGesture {
            isFocused = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you think that to enable the editing, we can somehow programmatically change the Z-index of the textfield and the overlay text? Perhaps use a ZStack rather than overlay. And when the user clicks on the text, we can just bring the Textfield to the front for editing, and update the char-array per edit... It's complex but thank you for the solution!

Comment: Possible but very complex likely prone to more bugs.

Comment: @PipEvangelist Actually, I figured out another way to do it. it looks a tiny bit off but a better version. It allows editing. The cursor is just a bit off

Comment: Thank you! This is brilliant