# Swift init of class

Tags: swift, class, initialization, core-location, viewdidload

I am pretty new to swift and can't get my head around the following code:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


class SpeedViewModel: UIViewController, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var speedtest = " km/h"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        print ("test1111")

        // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        // For use in foreground
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func updateLocationInfo(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees, speed: CLLocationSpeed, direction: CLLocationDirection) {
        let speedToKPH = (speed * 3.6)
            if (speedToKPH > 0) {
                speedtest = (String(format: "%.0f km/h", speedToKPH))
            } else {
                speedtest = "0 km/h"
            }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this code is not starting. Although it is not having any errors, it seems like the viewDidLoad() is never called and therefore the class is not doing anything to the rest of my app. Please help me to find the right initializer.

Comment: Where/how is `SpeedViewModel` being used/initialized?

Comment: that's the thing, I don't know where to initialize it, I created an object in the contentview  with 
@StateObject var speedViewModel = SpeedViewModel()
But it is not working because the viewDidload is apparently never called

Comment: That's the first time you mention that the question is about `SwiftUI`. `UIViewController` doesn't work stand-alone in SwiftUI. Replace `UIViewController` with `NSObject` – which is needed for the location manager delegate – and use a simple `init` method with the code in `viewDidLoad`. And you have to implement `didUpdateLocation` to get the current location.

Comment: Awesome that worked! but the speedtest variable is still unchanged " km/h".

Comment: `viewDidLoad` didn't get called because your view controller never had its view loaded. What you’ve done is to just initialize a new instance of this VC, but you haven’t actually tried to load its view (such as by placing its view in the view hierarchy). As Vadian said: you probably don’t want this class to be a view controller. I suspect you probably saw this in one of the many many many tutorials that inappropriately misuse a view controller as a `CLLocationManagerDelegate` (And likely also a text field delegate, a table data source and delegate, and the kitchen sink). Don’t do that.

Comment: `updateLocationInfo` is a custom method, not a delegate method.

Comment: okay, I understand. Please give me some advice so I can get the speed without calling the function or do you have an idea, how I can call it automatically?

Comment: @vadian : please be so kind and help me out here. I finally got 0 km/h, but the speed is not updated when Im moving. please give me some advice, how it can be updated

Comment: A `UIViewController` in the same `class` as an `ObservableObject` is not something that is possible if you are using SwiftUI any hacks are a bad solution. The `UIViewController` code needs to sit in a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` the ViewModel/`ObservableObject` can be shared separately. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70083022/swiftui-how-to-animate-each-character-in-textfield/70087100#70087100) setup. But you don't actually have `UIViewController` type code `UIView`s, `IBOutlet` `IBAction`, so just get rid of that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, rather than `UIViewController` declare the class as a subclass of `NSObject` and initialize the location manager in the standard `init` method.

`updateLocationInfo` is never being called by the framework. You have to implement `locationManager(_ didUpdateLocations:)` and get the speed from the location.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard let speed = locations.first?.speed else { return }
    let speedToKPH = speed * 3.6
    if speedToKPH > 0 {
        speedtest = String(format: "%.0f km/h", speedToKPH)
    } else {
        speedtest = "0 km/h"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. When im using this snippet, I get the error:
guard let speed = manager.locations.first?.speed else { return } Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: My bad, see the edit.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I do not know why, but I still can't get a speed reading... But im not sure if it is my phone or not, since other speed apps are not working either. Can you guess why?

Comment: I'm afraid, I have no idea.

Comment: is it feasible that the code killed the GPS module?

Comment: No, certainly not.

Answer (score -1):

my complete code looks now like this:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


class SpeedViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var lastLocation: CLLocation!
    var speedtest = " km/h"
    

    
    override init() {
        super.init()

        // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        // For use in foreground
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        guard let speed = locations.first?.speed else { return }
        let speedToKPH = speed * 3.6
        if speedToKPH > 0 {
            speedtest = String(format: "%.0f km/h", speedToKPH)
        } else {
            speedtest = "0 km/h"
        }
    }
}
```

and does what it should. Thank you @vadian